# VLANs and Bridges on Debian to share the same address

Tags: linux, debian, routing, switch, vlan

Right now I have a simple topology with the debian gateway, few managed switches and access points.

I'd like to add 3 VLANs to my topology and maybe use 802.1Q on  debian gateway, so that all the traffic between VLANs would go through the gateways firewall.

A lot of hosts in the network have manually configured gateway's IP.

This is where I need some help.

I'd like to use Linux bridge interface capabilities on Debian gateway, so that the physical port looking inside my network (eth1) would accept both new VLANs, frames without VLAN-id (untagged), while also being accessable with the same old IP via all new vlans. Something like what home Wi-Fi routers do.

How my topology and configuration should look like, assuming that I would use /etc/network/interfaces and VLAN package?

Do I just create VLANS on eth0, put "vlan_raw_device eth0" for every of them, and only set ip address for eth0 itself?

Or should I create a bridge, put all VLAN-interfaces and eth0 inside of it, and move IP address from eth0 to the bridge?

If, instead of gateway, I will make such configurations on end-point Devian, which endpoint's VLAN interface will be used for the outgoing traffic to the internet, if the device specified as default gateway also has both VLANS?

Do I have to put port on switch side to the trunk mode?

Are there any loop concerns, since switches may be uncapable of PVST.

Answer (score 0):

> so that the physical port looking inside my network (eth1) would accept both new VLANs, frames without VLAN-id (untagged)

That won't work. You need to configure a subinterface on your NIC with 802.1q VLAN tagging for each tagged VLAN trunked from the switch port.

> while also being accessable with the same old IP via all new vlans

That's also not possible: a VLAN is a layer-2 segment that needs to use its own IP subnet in order to enable routing. Since each gateway used by an end node needs to be part of the end node's subnet, you can't use an old gateway IP in a new subnet.

You can't use the old IP addresses and subnets with new VLANs either because for routing to work you need unambiguous, non-overlapping subnets.

If you bridge VLANs together, they essentially become one and you gain nothing.

The correct way to do it:

1. Configure subinterfaces on your Debian gateway and VLANs on the connecting switch. Trunk the VLANs (as tagged) between switch and gateway. Configure a (new) IP subnet for each subinterface and VLAN. Test connectivity.
2. Trunk the new VLANs to your other switches. Test connectivity.
3. Move your existing hosts to the intended VLANs (switch port in access mode and VLAN as untagged/native) - if necessary, one by one. Assign new IP addresses and default gateways. I'd recommend using DHCP for central IP management.

If you don't bridge on the gateway and don't create redundant links between switches, there's no need for RSTP/MSTP/RPVST+. I'd recommend considering it anyway as it provides good loop protection in case someone creates a backlink by accident. Just make sure that you select a good root bridge and put all edge ports in `portfast` or `admin-edge-port` mode, depending on switch vendor. And of course, *all* switches need to participate using the same protocol (RSTP and default MSTP interoperate, RPVST+ doesn't).

Comment: >a VLAN is a layer-2 segment that needs to use its own IP subnet in order to enable routing. 
Why can't I just use all VLAN subinterfaces to forward L2 traffic to the bridge interface?
Like
``` 

Vlan1 ----|Br1             | 
Vlan2 ----|192.168.1.1|
```

Comment: E.g., IIRC, Mikrotiks ports might be put into L2 only levels, set to different vlans, but as long as they are within the same bridge - everything works. 
My asus WiFi router somehow has an IP address on the bridge interface, and puts bridged interfaces (VLAN1+ra0+ra1) into the same subnet.

Should I try my luck with assymetrics VLANs?

Comment: What's the point of setting up different VLANs when you bridge them all together, so they become one?

Comment: Im trying to achieve 2 things: 1) To prevent talking hosts from one vlan to another talking directly. 2) To pass all the traffic between vlans through firewall traffic rules. If I just put FW rules on my router, it wont affect the traffic that doesn't go through router, which is the case when both hosts in the same broadcast domain. 
My switches doesn't have any L2 firewalls, so I guess thats the easiest way to do achieve filtering.

Comment: Im also concerned about the traffic, that goes from "outside" and was untagged. If i change my link between Debian-RTR and switch to the trunk mode, which VLAN tag debian would use? Does conntrack work with vlans? Or will it mirror all the outside traffic to all existing VLAN subinterfaces?